# Laravel UpdateOrCreate To Be Different values on Create on Update

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Is there something like UpdateOrCreate I can use to have different values on create and on update. Meaning if it’s updating i don’t want it to change a certain column but i want it to insert the first time.
eg

```
$person = ['name'=> 'John', 'age' => 6, 'joined' => '2017-01-01'];
```

If John exists update age. If it doesn’t insert age and joined;

```
People::updateOrCreate(
            ['name' => $person['name']],
            ['age' => $person['age'], 'joined' => $person['joined']]
        )
```

will update joined every time and i don't wanna change it.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `updateOrNew` which doesn't persist it to the database and then check if it is not already in the database you can change the property you want to change.

```
$record = People::updateOrNew(
        ['name' => $person['name']],
        ['age' => $person['age']]
);

if(!$record->exists()) {
    $record->joined = $person['joined'];
}

$record->save();
```

But if you are only trying to get the record if it exists and create it if it doesn't, use `firstOrCreate()` instead. That won't affect existing records, only return them, and it will create the record if it doesn't exist.

Comment: `updateOrNew` [doesn't seem](https://laravel.com/api/10.x/search.html?search=updateOrNew) to be a real method

Answer (score 1):

There is no any other option else you can try following:

```
 $person = People::where('name', $name)->first();
  
        if (!is_null($person)) {
            $person->update([
                'age' => $age
            ]);
        }else{
            $person = People::create([
                'name' => $name,
                'age' => $age,
                'joined' => date('Y-m-d')
            ]);
        }
```